# ERROR when creating User on an ASP.NET MVC2 Project on a server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I have uploaded the ASP.NET MVC2 created from MS Template to Remote server. It works except when I want to register a new user; after validation I got this error message:

> Sorry, an error occurred while
>   processing your request.

What should I do ?

Comment: You should see what the error actually is.

Answer (score 1):

I would suspect that the database location is not writeable but as [Remus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/105929/remus-rusanu) said to know for sure you'll need to get the error/exception back from the server somehow.

Answer (score 1):

You need to allow write access to the `~/App_Data` directory to the account your application is configured to run under IIS. When you try to register a user for the first time the application need to create the `.mdb` database file. Also if you are not using SQL Express and  have a SQL Server installed don't forget to modify the connection string in your web.config to match the properties of your real server.

Comment: Sorry I'm novice in basic settings I have pass-through authentication so to which account should I give write access ?

Comment: In Application Pool I have set Identity to Administrator to be sure it has access right but it doesn't seem to solve.

Comment: @user310291, for configuring IIS you might have better luck asking your question on http://serverfault.com. StackOverflow is a programming related Q&A site. If you have troubles configuring your web server SF is better suited.